# (VB6) Run-time error ‘-2147217864(80040e38)’: Row cannot be located for updating. Some values may have been changed since it was last read

Tags: mysql, vb6

i have a process that will update the records of the material. but first it will get the existing records of the material like avail quantity before updating and when i try to update it with the new one. i get an error saying "Run-time error ‘-2147217864(80040e38)’: Row cannot be located for updating. Some values may have been changed since it was last read."

```
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim coy As String
If Left(Text4.Text, 3) = "800" Then
For i = 1 To ListView2.ListItems.Count
With ListView2.ListItems(i)
If rs.State <> 0 Then rs.Close
     rs.Open "Select * from Inventory where InventoryID = " & Val(.ListSubItems(6).Text), db, 3, 3
     If rs.RecordCount <> 0 Then
       'get average cost start
        Dim avgcost, Stockqty, newstockqty As Double
        Stockqty = CDbl(rs!AvailQty) * CDbl(rs!unitprice)
        newstockqty = CDbl(.ListSubItems(7).Text) * CDbl(.ListSubItems(8).Text)
        avgcost = (Stockqty + newstockqty) / CDbl(CDbl(rs!AvailQty) + 
CDbl(.ListSubItems(7).Text))
       'get average cost end

       rs!avecost = FormatNumber(avgcost, 3)
       avaiqtyparam = CDbl(rs!AvailQty) + CDbl(.ListSubItems(7).Text)
      rs!AvailQty = CDbl(rs!AvailQty) + CDbl(.ListSubItems(7).Text)
       rs!unitprice = FormatNumber(CDbl(.ListSubItems(8).Text), 5)
       rs!lastupdate = FormatDateTime(DTPicker1.Value, vbShortDate)

       Dim AvgVat, stockvat, nestockvat As Double

       stockvat = CDbl(rs!AvailQty) * CDbl(rs!AvailVAT)
       nestockvat = CDbl(.ListSubItems(7).Text) * CDbl(.ListSubItems(11).Text)
       AvgVat = (stockvat + nestockvat) / CDbl(CDbl(rs!AvailQty) + 
 CDbl(.ListSubItems(11).Text))
       rs!AvailVAT = CDbl(.ListSubItems(11).Text)
       rs!AveVAT = FormatNumber(AvgVat, 3)
       rs.Update
     End If
End With
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Next i
```

Comment: just additional info i have a primary key for this table.

Comment: upupupupupupupupupupup

Comment: your nesting is wrong, move up `rs.close`

Comment: where before "end with"?

Comment: upupupupupupupuupup